# I can't add id from XML

Tags: kotlin

[image]

Why can't I add this id  here?

Comment: I try fix error but it isnt working, I cant see import on settings in fix error page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the `TextView` directly from the `itemView` you should use `findViewById`:

```
holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTodoTitle).apply {
    // Initialize the TextView here...
    text = "Example"
}
```

Comment: I try it but it isnt working

Comment: Like you say  

holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTodoTitle).apply {
            tvTodoTitle
        }

Comment: By using `apply` you can access the `TextView` directly by using the `it` object, or you can omit the `it` and customize the `TextView` directly. Check out the edited answer for an example.